# I want to make Location Base AR in Swift 3.0, ARkit

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, core-location, arkit

I'm japanese and I'm a beginner. This is first time that i post to stackoverflow.

Now, I am trying to make location base AR app, that specific objects appear in specific position, using ARkit and CoreLocation.
For example, sphere3Node appear in latitude > 35.5 (refer in my source code).
This code is working successfully, but sphere3Node cannot appear in screen.

```
    import SceneKit
    import ARKit
    import CoreLocation
    import UIKit

    class ViewController: UIViewController, ARSCNViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate{

        var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        var locationData : CLLocation? = nil

        @IBOutlet weak var idoLabel: UILabel!
        @IBOutlet weak var keidoLabel: UILabel!
        @IBOutlet weak var hyoukouLabel: UILabel!
        @IBOutlet weak var hanteiLabel: UILabel!

          private let label: UILabel = UILabel()

        @IBOutlet var sceneView: ARSCNView!



        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            locationManager = CLLocationManager()
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
            locationManager.delegate = self
            setupLocationService()

            self.sceneView = ARSCNView(frame: self.view.frame)


             self.label.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: self.sceneView.frame.size.width, height:50 )
             self.label.center = self.sceneView.center
             self.label.textAlignment = .center  
             self.label.textColor = UIColor.red
             self.label.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .headline)
             self.label.alpha = 0

            self.sceneView.addSubview(self.label)

            self.sceneView.debugOptions = [ARSCNDebugOptions.showFeaturePoints,ARSCNDebugOptions.showWorldOrigin]   

            self.view.addSubview(self.sceneView)

            // Set the view's delegate
            sceneView.delegate = self

            // Show statistics such as fps and timing information
            sceneView.showsStatistics = true

            // Create a new scene
            let scene = SCNScene()

            // box blue
            //Color Setting , random
            let random: CGFloat = CGFloat(arc4random() % 10) 
            let r: CGFloat = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(255)+1) / 255.0
            let g: CGFloat = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(255)+1) / 255.0
            let b: CGFloat = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(255)+1) / 255.0
            //let color: UIColor = UIColor(red: r, green: g, blue: b, alpha: 1.0)

            // node (Box)
            let box = SCNBox(width: 0.2, height: 0.2, length: 0.2, chamferRadius: 0)  
            let material = SCNMaterial()
            material.diffuse.contents = UIColor(red:r, green:g, blue:b, alpha: 1)
            let node = SCNNode()
            node.geometry = box
            material.name = "Color"
            node.geometry?.materials = [material]
            node.position = SCNVector3(0, 0.2, -1)

            //Object Setting

            // sphereNode green
            let sphere = SCNSphere(radius: 0.2) 
            let sphereMaterial = SCNMaterial()
            // sphereMaterial.diffuse.contents = UIColor.green
            sphereMaterial.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "earthmap.jpeg")
            let sphereNode = SCNNode()
            sphereNode.geometry = sphere
            sphereNode.geometry?.materials = [sphereMaterial]
            sphereNode.position = SCNVector3(0.5, 0.1, -1)   

            // sphere2Node red
            let sphere2 = SCNSphere(radius: 0.1)  
            let sphere2Material = SCNMaterial()
            sphere2Material.diffuse.contents = UIColor.red
            let sphere2Node = SCNNode()
            sphere2Node.geometry = sphere2
            sphere2Node.geometry?.materials = [sphere2Material]
            sphere2Node.position = SCNVector3(0.4, 0.1, -3)

            // sphere3Node blue 
            let sphere3 = SCNSphere(radius: 0.1) 
            let sphere3Material = SCNMaterial()
            sphere3Material.diffuse.contents = UIColor.blue
            let sphere3Node = SCNNode()
            sphere3Node.geometry = sphere3
            sphere3Node.geometry?.materials = [sphere3Material]
            sphere3Node.position = SCNVector3(0.6, 0.2, -3)


            scene.rootNode.addChildNode(node)
            scene.rootNode.addChildNode(sphereNode)
            scene.rootNode.addChildNode(sphere2Node)


            if let locationData = locationData, locationData.coordinate.latitude > 35.5 {
            scene.rootNode.addChildNode(sphere3Node)
            }

            let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapped))  
            self.sceneView.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)

            // Set the scene to the view
            sceneView.scene = scene
        }

        //objective-C func tapped
        @objc func tapped(recognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
            let sceneView = recognizer.view as! SCNView   
            let touchLocation = recognizer.location(in: sceneView)    
            let hitResults = sceneView.hitTest(touchLocation, options: [:])   
            if !hitResults.isEmpty {     
                let node = hitResults[0].node   
                let material = node.geometry?.material(named: "Color")  
                material?.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "earthmap.jpeg")    
            }
        }

        override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
            super.viewWillAppear(animated)

            // Create a session configuration
            let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
             configuration.planeDetection = .horizontal  

            // Run the view's session
            sceneView.session.run(configuration)
        }

        override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
            super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

            // Pause the view's session
            sceneView.session.pause()
        }

        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
            // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
        }

        // MARK: - ARSCNViewDelegate
            func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {

         DispatchQueue.main.async{
         self.label.text = "plane detected"
         UIView.animate(withDuration: 3.0, animations: {
         self.label.alpha = 1.0
         }){(completion: Bool) in
         self.label.alpha = 0.0
                }
                }
         }

        /*
         // Override to create and configure nodes for anchors added to the view's session.
         func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, nodeFor anchor: ARAnchor) -> SCNNode? {
         let node = SCNNode()

         return node
         }
         */

        func session(_ session: ARSession, didFailWithError error: Error) {
            // Present an error message to the user

        }

        func sessionWasInterrupted(_ session: ARSession) {
            // Inform the user that the session has been interrupted, for example, by presenting an overlay

        }

        func sessionInterruptionEnded(_ session: ARSession) {
            // Reset tracking and/or remove existing anchors if consistent tracking is required

        }

        //location
        func setupLocationService(){
            locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
            locationManager.distanceFilter = 1
        }

        func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager,
                             didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
            switch status{
            case .authorizedAlways, .authorizedWhenInUse :

                locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
            case .notDetermined:
                locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
            //disabledLocationLabel()
            default:
                locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
                //disabledLocationLabel()
            }
        }

        private func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, 
            didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]){
            let locationData = locations.last

            if var ido = locationData?.coordinate.latitude {
                ido = round(ido*1000000)/100000
            }
              if var keido = locationData?.coordinate.longitude{
                keido = round(keido*1000000)/1000000
            }
            if var hyoukou = locationData?.altitude{
                hyoukou = round(hyoukou*100)/100
            }
        }


    }
```

That's all.Thank you.

Comment: Why are you doing this? `ido = round(ido*1000000)/100000`

Comment: In japanese, ido means latitude,and i want that latitude is double type.(according to my text books)

Comment: yeah? so why round it, multiply it and divide it.  `if var ido = locationData?.coordinate.latitude` ido is Double value already

Comment: ok,i see. so,it don't need "ido = round(ido*1000000)/100000".Thank you.but, this problem is not solved.